# Posting from one ActionResult to another

Tags: http, model-view-controller

I have an ActionResult method that accepts a post from an outside form.  The form sender can only adhere to their naming convention in terms of what their parameters are called, and my application can only adhere to another naming convention.  As a result, I need to create a bridge that accepts a post, and sends another post.  The issue I'm having is that only parameters from the original post are showing up in the Request.Form collection.

So to be clear:  I'm looking for TokenA and TokenB but I'm still only seeing token_A and token_B.

Here is the method that I'm using to handle this.  I'm not sure if my new Http Request is correct, but it should be given that I'm just using what's listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FormPost()
    {
        string TokenA = string.Empty;
        string TokenB = string.Empty;

        TokenA = Request.Form["token_A"].ToString();
        TokenB = Request.Form["token_B"].ToString();

        System.Net.WebRequest webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:17159/Login/TokenAcceptor");
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data;";
        var postData = "TokenB=" + TokenB + "&TokenA=" + TokenA;
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        webRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        System.Net.WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();

        var sso = SsoFactory.Get(SsoType.FormPost);
        var ssoIdentity = sso.GetSsoIdentity();

        return TokenAcceptor();
    }
```

Comment: You're not doing anything with `response`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't post to another method and pass the values along.

You *can* get around this by writing data from the first post into 'TempData' then,

`return RedirectToAction('MethodNameHere');`

and reading it out in the second post method. This works well although its probably something that would be frowned upon. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @DubstepCat.  I'm going to take a look at re-writing this code at a later date.  :-)

Comment: No problem. If you google 'how to use TempData in MVC' you should find enough info to get you going with writing stuff into that array and then reading it out again. Good luck!